# Списки в Python из файла

Tags: python-3.x, функции, list, файловый-ввод-вывод

Есть текстовый файл с именами и очками пользователей, например:
Lisa 60
Fifa 0
Elka 140
Надо выдернуть эти данные в список (что бы имя было в столбце name, очки - в ochki), далее, если имя пользователя (которое он ввел ранее) есть в списке - то изменение его количества очков, если нету - новая запись в списке (по умолчанию кол-во очков нового пользователя 0), а далее выгрузка всего этого дела обратно в файл. Как это сделать? У меня получилось выгрузить файл в список, но такая выгрузка объединяет имена и очки пользователей в одну строку, из-за чего работа только с одним параметром (именем или очками) - не возможна.

```
   import sys 
class Igrok():
    name = 'imya'
    ochki = 0
#polsovatel = Igrok()
#polsovatel.name = input("Введите имя игрока")
def read2list(first_file):
    first_file = open('C:\\Users\\Professional\\Desktop\\Tokarev\\table.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    indata = first_file.read()
    table = indata.split("\n")
    return(table)
    first_file.close()
table = read2list('table.txt')
print(table)
```

текстовый файл (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wXt.png)

вывод (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeFO2.png)

Comment: Текстовый файл и вывод прикрепите текстом

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, у тебя проблема с парсингом данных из файла, **вот тебе парсер, где и как применять думаю догадаешься сам.**

```
def parse(data: str) -> dict:
    result = dict()
    data = data.split('\n')  # Разбиваем по строкам

    for line in data:
        l = line.split()  # l[0] Имя, l[1] очки
        result.update({l[0]: int(l[1])})

    return result
```

Насколько я понял, тебе нужно будет сделать ещё и наоборот. **Из словаря в файл**.

```
def parse_to_file(parsed_data: dict) -> str:
    result = list()
    for key, val in parsed.data.items():
        result.append(f"{key} {val}")
    return '\n'.join(result)
```

Результат `parse("Alan 0\nPaul 1")` будет `{"Alan": 0, "Paul": 1}`, а результат `parse_to_file({"Sam": 5, "Alan": 20})` будет `Sam 5\nAlan 20`, Уже это значение можно записывать в файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
for name, ochki in (line.split() for line in f.readlines()):
    print(name,ochki,username)
```

Answer (score 0):

думаю лучше данные такого рода хранить в csv файле

но модуль csv и с текстовым файлом справляется, так что можно попробовать такой способ (данные игроков в файле на отдельных строках, имена и очки разделены пробелом):

```
import csv
new_scores = {'joe':100,'mark':500}  # данные для обновление очков игроков
file_path = r'table.txt'  # путь к вашему файлу

with open(file_path, newline='') as file:
    scores = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
    d = {k:int(v) for k,v in scores}  # считали данные из файла в словарь
    print(d)
    for k,v in new_scores.items():  # добавляем в словарь очки и новых игроков
        d[k] = d.get(k,0) + v
    print(d)  # обновленный словарь
    
with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'score']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=' ')
    for k,v in d.items():
        writer.writerow({'name': k, 'score': v})  # записываем новый словарь в файл
```

print (данные для примера):

```
{'joe': 10, 'helen': 20, 'bob': 30, 'luci': 40, 'donald': 50}
{'joe': 110, 'helen': 20, 'bob': 30, 'luci': 40, 'donald': 50, 'mark': 500}
```